# Modified date in File Explorer CHANGES even if I am just HOVERING over the date and have not opened the document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, date-modified

I can see there are solutions to fix, but I cannot go and change hundreds of documents manually.  I never experienced this problem in nearly 30 years of using Word and Excel.  It started last fall or slightly earlier when I simply opened and closed a file, but made no changes at all.  Today is the first time I noticed the change when just hovering.  I've been looking at ways to fix but have yet to find anything.

Comment: This effect is really strange. Does it happen if you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: Do you use Google Drive? If yes, this is applicable: https://support.google.com/a/thread/10564946/windows-10-google-file-stream-modifying-document-dates-when-entering-a-folder?hl=en

Comment: Does it happen for all file types (e.g., `,txt`, `.jpg`, `.pdf`, `.zip`, …) or just Microsoft Office files?  Old formats (`.doc` and `.xls`), new formats (`.docx` and `.xlsx`), or both?  Are the files *actually* modified?   What if you take a text file `foo.txt` and rename it to `foo.doc`?  What is displayed on the screen when you hover?   What versions (of Windows and Microsoft Office)? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.